# JavaScript return data

Tags: javascript, cordova

for reading data from file in `PhoneGap` i make s simple class in which i access file like below code

```
var ReaderForFile =
{
    dataFromFile:null,
    start_ReadFile:function()
    {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, ReaderForFile.got_FileSystemReader, ReaderForFile.fail);
    },
    got_FileSystemReader:function(fileSystem)
    {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("SHA_ErrorLog.txt", null, ReaderForFile.got_FileEntry, ReaderForFile.fail);
    },
    got_FileEntry:function(fileEntry)
    {
        fileEntry.file(ReaderForFile.got_File, ReaderForFile.fail);
    },
    got_File:function(file)
    {
        ReaderForFile.read_AsText(file);
    },
    read_AsText:function(file)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            ReaderForFile.dataFromFile = evt.target.result+"}]}";
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    },
    fail:function()
    {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    },
    getData:function()
    {
        ReaderForFile.start_ReadFile();
        return ReaderForFile.dataFromFile;
    }
}
```

Then I call the function like that

```
var data = ReaderForFile.getData();
```

But in this data always return `null` because it return before all functions executes what should I do here that it return when `read_AsText` executes fully and data be store in `dataFromFile` variable

Answer (score 0):

Best way here is to use callBack functions for the same.As your function is executing asynchronously hence it will written null each time.

[Tutorial for callback functions in JavaScript](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them)